# Loop through nested field in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, loops, constructor

I've made 2 classes, first one is making JTextFields, the second one injects those JTextFields into a JPanel. I am trying to .setText to every JTextField but simple

```
    for (Field f: fields) {
    f.setValue("my text");
    }
```

doesn't work - it sets text only to JTextFields within one JPanel. As every of JTextFields have uniqe fieldID, could you please tell me how to setText (setValue) to them? These values need to be set outside of the loops, using ActionListener.

```
public class Field {

    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    static int fieldID = 0;
    private String text;
    public Field() {
        fieldID++;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return field.getText();
    }

    public void setValue(String text) {
        field.setText(text);
    }
} 

public class Frame extends JFrame {

public Frame() {
    Field[] fields = new Field[9];
    JPanel[] corePane = new JPanel[9];
    JPanel frontPane = new JPanel();
    frontPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    for (int i = 0; i < corePane.length; i++) {
        corePane[i] = new JPanel();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            fields[j] = new Field();
            corePane[i].add(fields[j].field);
        }
        corePane[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        frontPane.add(corePane[i]);
    }

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(300, 300);
    getContentPane().add(frontPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Frame::new);
}
}
```

Comment: So, your `fields` probably needs to be a two dimensional array, for example `Field[][] fields = new Field[9][9];`.  This way, you can access the fields (second dimension) for a given panel (first dimension), ie `fields[pane][field]`.  Obviously, in your `for-loop`, you will need to initialise the array for the fields properly, for example, `fields[I] = new Field[9]`;

Comment: Seems like the text fields should be replaced by one `JTable` (but there is not enough detail about the purpose of them for me to tell for certain). General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `public class Frame extends JFrame {` there is no good case here to extend `JFrame`. Just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `fields` probably needs to be a two dimensional array, for example

```
Field[][] fields = new Field[9][9];
```

This way, you can access the fields (second dimension) for a given panel (first dimension), ie `fields[pane][field]`.

Obviously, in your `for-loop`, you will need to initialise the array for the fields properly, for example, `fields[i] = new Field[9]`;

This might make your code look something more like...

```
public class Field {

    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    static int fieldID = 0;
    private String text;

    public Field() {
        fieldID++;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return field.getText();
    }

    public void setValue(String text) {
        field.setText(text);
    }
}

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        Field[][] fields = new Field[9][9];
        JPanel[] corePane = new JPanel[9];
        JPanel frontPane = new JPanel();
        frontPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < corePane.length; i++) {
            corePane[i] = new JPanel();
            fields[i] = new Field[9];
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                fields[i][j] = new Field();
                corePane[i].add(fields[i][j].field);
            }
            corePane[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            frontPane.add(corePane[i]);
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(300, 300);
        getContentPane().add(frontPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Frame::new);
    }
}
```

Now, a word of `static`

```
static int fieldID = 0;
```

will mean that every instance of `Field` will have the same `fieldID`, regardless of what you change it to.  To me (and based on what you've said), it doesn't make sense to use `static` in this way

There are alternatives to this, which might provide better and more re-usable solution

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the solution of @MadProgrammer I can offer you some useful method, that can help you to solve these tasks without to declare any arrays.

```
/**
 * Searches for all children of the given component which are instances of the given class.
 *
 * @param aRoot start object for search. May not be null.
 * @param aClass class to search. May not be null.
 * @param <E> class of component.
 * @return list of all children of the given component which are instances of the given class. Never null.
 */
public static <E> List<E> getAllChildrenOfClass(Container aRoot, Class<E> aClass) {
    return getAllChildrenOfClass(aRoot, aClass, e -> true);
}

/**
 * Searches for all children of the given component which are instances of the given class and satisfies the given condition.
 *
 * @param aRoot start object for search. May not be null.
 * @param aClass class to search. May not be null.
 * @param condition condition to be satisfied. May not be null.
 * @param <E> class of component.
 * @return list of all children of the given component which are instances of the given class. Never null.
 */
public static <E> List<E> getAllChildrenOfClass(Container aRoot, Class<E> aClass, Predicate<E> condition) {
    final List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final Component[] children = aRoot.getComponents();
    for (final Component c : children) {
        if (aClass.isInstance(c) && condition.test(aClass.cast(c))) {
            result.add(aClass.cast(c));
        }
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            result.addAll(getAllChildrenOfClass((Container) c, aClass, condition));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can set text for all your text fields.

```
getAllChildrenOfClass(getContentPane(), JTextField.class).forEach(tf -> tf.setText("My text"));
```